# what does spin up mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

this sentence is about programming, but I don't know what the meaning of "spin up" as follows is.

> We're doing that by using a class from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting,
>   and that is the web host class that has a static method that makes
>   this easy to "**spin up**" a web server, it's called CreateDefaultBuilder,
>   and once I have a web host builder, I need to configure that builder a
>   little bit.

Comment: "Spin up", in this context, relies on two separate metaphors.  "Spinning" is the first step in making cloth from fleece or cotton.  (OK, "carding" comes first, but everyone ignores that.)  And when you play a "record" (remember those?) you "spin up" the platter before placing the needle on the record.  Both convey a sense of getting things started, and so "spin up" means "get started" in a number of industries.

Comment: @HotLicks care to write that up as an answer?

Comment: @Lambie Getting things to move faster has nothing to do with speed?

Comment: @Lambie - The term was in use long before hard disks.

Comment: Benny Goodman recorded "Spin a Record" in 1949: https://jdisc.columbia.edu/session/benny-goodman-september-18-1949

Comment: And "spin up" meaning to weave a web goes back to the 1800s and was transferred to the textile industry.  I'll note that this usage fits creating something for the "web" better than spinning a disk does.

Comment: @HotLicks It is a rotating disk aka a spinning disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all incorrect. In computer science, the term originally referred to part of the process of starting a hard disk drive. HDDs have platters that spin. When a HDD starts, the platter "spins up." It is used as a metaphor when describing virtual machines that do not actually have a physical HDD or machines that contain a SSD. Source is me - a professional IT worker.

Comment: This answer really would be better as a comment, since there isn't a reference given (and I don't think one exists). There are references for spin-up in the context of platter disks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-up).

Comment: 'In computer science, the term originally referred to part of the process of starting a hard disk drive.' (a) doesn't mean exactly the same as 'the term originated in computer science, and referred to part of the process of starting a hard disk drive.' (it is quite likely that the term was first used by say DJs), but (b) doesn't license 'this is all incorrect'. One usage may well have led to another. Perhaps 'These answers are inadequate'?

Comment: This answer has the virtue of being context related. Rather than a dictionary definition floating in the ether.

Comment: "Spin up" is a reference to any and all motors, flywheels, turbines, and the like, and not to disk drives in particular.

Comment: The first sentence may be easier to understand if you know that in many early machines, the disk provided the reference clock signal. The cpu was slaved to the disk. Literally the only thing you had to do to turn on these machines was spin up the disk. Navigation electronics are spun up because the first INSs had [PIGAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIGA_accelerometer) and gyro compasses.

Answer (score 3):

For the unbelievers, here's the definition:

> Definition - What does Spin-Up mean? Spin-up is when a disk in a disk
>   drive speeds up to the required revolutions per minute for effective
>   writing to or reading from the disk. Conventional hard disk drives
>   have one or more platters that revolve mechanically on a spindle while
>   reading and writing elements alter the magnetic surface of the disk.

[Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/27697/spin-up)PLUS

A hard disk drive (HDD), hard disk, hard drive, or fixed disk[b] is an electro-mechanical data storage device that uses magnetic storage to store and retrieve digital information using one or more rigid rapidly **rotating disks** [SPINNING] (platters) coated with magnetic material. The platters are paired with magnetic heads, usually arranged on a moving actuator arm, which read and write data to the platter surfaces.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive) Data is accessed in a random-access manner, meaning that individual blocks of data can be stored or retrieved in any order and not only sequentially. HDDs are a type of non-volatile storage, retaining stored data even when powered off.[3](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/spin-up)[4][5]

Introduced by IBM in 1956,[6] HDDs were the dominant secondary storage device for general-purpose computers beginning in the early 1960s. HDDs maintained this position into the modern era of servers and personal computers.

[hard disk drive and spinning (rotating)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)

**And finally, in this day and age:**

**spin up**
in British English from the Collins Dictionary

VERB

(tr, adverb) computing
**to create (a virtual machine) using a cloud-computing service**
**to spin up a new server**
[spin up a server](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/spin-up)

Comment: "Spin up" is a reference to any and all motors, flywheels, turbines, and the like, and not to disk drives in particular.

Comment: @BenVoigt That is irrelevant here. Though I would have thought **Crank it up** would apply more to motors. Crank up the AC, Charlie!

Answer (score 0):

To spin up a web server (a software application) is to create it rapidly.

> Definition of spin
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 a : to draw out and twist into yarns or threads   b : **to produce**
>   by drawing out and twisting a fibrous material
>
> 2 : **to form** (something, such as a web or cocoon) by spinning
>
> 3 a : to stretch out or extend (something, such as a story) lengthily
>   : protract —usually used with out   b : **to evolve, express, or
>   fabricate by processes of mind or imagination** spin a yarn
>
> 4 : to cause to whirl : impart spin to spin a top
>
> 5 : to shape into threadlike form in manufacture; also : **to
>   manufacture by a whirling process**
>
> 6 : to set (records or compact
>   discs) rotating on a player : play spin some discs
>
> 7 : to present
>   (information) with a particular spin spin the statistics

[Spin (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spin)

Comment: This might be more useful if you explained how the dictionary definition of "spin" you have quoted relates to the colloquial "spin up".